# Calculating sun exposure limit over changing UV index

Tags: dermatology, uv-rays, sun-burn

I'm currently working on an engineering project which monitors the users current UV exposure and attempts to calculate how much time they can safely remain in the sun. An issue I've encountered is finding a method for actually making a calculation and summation of how much "sun" someone has received based on their skin tone over a changing UV reading. The UV index seems to give guidelines for exposure time but I cannot find anything that can be put into numbers.